# Would Martian sunrise/sunset look the same at the Thaumasia Plateau as the rovers' photographs?

Tags: mars, naked-eye, sunrise

If observing the sunrise or sunset, with the naked eye, from the Thaumasia Plateau (app. 260°, -10°), [6 kilometers above Mars elevation zero](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/mars/mars-orbiter-laser-altimeter.html),[image]

would it have the same [blue hue](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/925/what-does-a-sunrise-sunset-look-like-on-mars/) as the images of the sunrise/sunsets taken by the NASA rovers below elevation zero?

Would a higher elevation sunrise/sunset look any different because the atmosphere is less dense?

[image]

Comment: slightly related and currently unanswered: [Terrestrial Exoplanet Skies – I've Built a Visual Sky Chart. Is it Accurate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24048/7982)